# Regex to get all numbers after a character

Tags: php, regex

I have strings that are expected to be in the format of something like

`"C 1,13,7,2,55"`
I would expect matches to be `[1,13,7,2,55]`.

I want to match on all numbers in that "csv" portion of the string. But only if it comes after "C " Note a space after the 'c'

This comes from user-input and so I want to account for case and multiple space(s) in between tokens and accidental double commas, etc..

I.e.
`"c    1   ,  12,15     ,   8     ,   9,10,11"`
I want matches to be `[1,12,15,8,9,10,11]`

But I only want to attempt to match on numbers after the "C" char (case-insensitive).

So `"1,2  ,  4,5"` and `"d 12456, 9890"` should fail .

Here's the regex I have half-baked so far.

Note: This will ultimately get ported over to `PHP` and so I will be using `preg_match_all`

`/(?<=C)*\d+/gim`

I use a positive lookbehind (but match as many times as needed) for the "C" char. Then match on 1 or more digits globally.

I haven't created all my unit tests yet, but I think this may work.

Is there a better way to do this?
Is matching on 1or more positive lookbehinds standard?

Why don't I need to include a `\s*` after the `'C'` in the positive lookbehind?
When would including the `'m'` multi-line flag even make a difference here?

Thanks!

Comment: You could explode on `C ` then `preg_split` on integers. That would probably be easiest... this seems more like a technical regex question though, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, more of a technical regex one. If you feel it's objectively more appropriate to do this wo regex and use string methods, then I'll consider that too. Just kinda assumed regex is best way to solve this, but perhaps not

Comment: @user3783243 I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't yield what I'm looking for. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fe33b70150637a1ac8e53b49629524d926980ee

Comment: It would be inverted but it wouldn't validate the data actually.  https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fe33b70150637a1ac8e53b49629524d926980ee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to first test for the `"C"` using the case-insensitive `stripos` before matching the digits with `\d+`. For example:

```php
$input = "c    1   ,  12,15     ,   8     ,   9,10,11";

if (stripos($input, "C") === 0) {
    preg_match_all("/\d+/", $input, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

The condition could be for example `stripos($input, "C") !== false` if the `"C"` does not have to be the first character.

To validate that the string starts with `"C"` (possibly after horizontal whitespace), and contains only horizontal whitespace, commas and digits then the test could instead be

```php
if (preg_match("/^\h*C[\h\d,]+$/i", $input)) {
```

The lookbehind in your regex `/(?<=C)*\d+/gim` is made optional by the `*`, so the regex does not require that a `"C"` is present for the digits to be matched. It is functionally equivalent to just `/\d+/g`.

> Is matching on 1 or more positive lookbehinds standard?

In this case, the lookbehind would need to be variable-width `(?<=C.*)` and php does not support variable-width lookbehinds.

> Why don't I need to include a `\s*` after the `'C'` in the positive lookbehind?

Php does not support the use of the `*` quantifier inside a lookbehind.

> When would including the 'm' multi-line flag even make a difference here?

You only might want to use the `m` flag if your input is multi-lined and you are using `^` or `$` which assert the start or end respectively of a line or the whole string.

Comment: Appreciate a lot of the clarifications. The 2-step process to first check if "C" exists and has commas, spaces, digits, does make things a lot cleaner. I guess I was trying to see if I can do this all in 1 straight shot with a Regex. I'll play around with this soln and the answer above to determine what I want to do.

I know this is subjective, but what's your $0.02 on choosing between complex regex vs multiple checks (ik regexes can be expensive too) Execution time doesn't matter much here in my use case anyways

Comment: Any way to modify `preg_match_all("/\d+/", $input, $matches);` to exclude digits contained within parentheses? I.e. "C 1(2), 4 ( 4 )"
i'd expect `[1,4]` and not `[1,2,4,4]`. 
I tried `/(?!\(\d+\))\d+/gim` to no avail

Comment: @user2402616 There are many different ways depending on what the string may contain (which seems to be changing). For example: `"/\d+\b(?!\h*\))/"`

Answer (score 1):

Using this pattern `/(?<=C)*\d+/gim;` in for example Javascript it would not be valid due to the quantifier after the lookbehind assertion.

If you want to write it in JavaScript getting all the digits after `C`  at the start of the string, and the [quantifier in the lookbehind is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind):

```
(?<=^C [\d, ]*)\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pByZEW/1)

Using `(?<=C)*\d+` in PHP, the quantifier for the lookbehind is optional, and it would also match 8 and 9 in for example this string `8,9 C 1,13,7,2,55`

Using a quantifier with infinite length in a lookbehind assertion is not supported in PHP so you can not use `(?<=C\h+)\d+` where `\h+` would match 1+ spaces due to `S`

---

If you are using PHP, you can make use of the [\G anchor](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G) to match only consecutive numbers after the first `C` character.

For a single line, you don't need the multi line flag. You do need it for [multiple lines](https://regex101.com/r/RQZWNJ/1) due to the [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

```
(?:^\h*C\h+|\G(?!^))\h*,*\h*\K\d+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^` Start of string
  - `\h*C\h+` Match optional spaces, then `C` and 1+ spaces
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match (not at the start)
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\h*,*\h*\K` Match optional comma's between optional spaces
- `\d+` Match 1 or more digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/53ZsVP/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/SdCDj)

```
$regex = '/(?:\h*C\h+|\G(?!^))\h*,*\h*\K\d+/i';
$strings = [
    "C 1,13,7,2,55",
    "c    1   ,  12,15     ,   8     ,   9,10,11",
    "1,2  ,  4,5",
    "d 12456, 9890"
];

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    if (preg_match_all($regex, $s, $matches)) {
        print_r($matches[0]);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 55
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 10
    [6] => 11
)
```

Comment: Is the lazy match and word boundary part of the first part of the OR clause in the non-cap group needed? `?\b`. Looks like all matches still work wo that.  https://3v4l.org/krsW7 seems to be down.

Comment: @user2402616 The pattern first matches till the first occurrence of `C ` which is the first part of the alternation and uses a non greedy quantifier to match the first occurrence. The `\G` anchor can only continue if that first match is there. If the `C ` should be at the start of the string you can shorten the pattern to `(?:\h*C|\G(?!^))\h*,*\h*\K\d+` https://regex101.com/r/zJwYYo/1

Comment: Is it a simple modification to exclude digits contained inside parentheses too?
I.e....I can expect certain strings like "C 1(2), 12 (  4  ), 13 ( 3)", etc...

So I'd want to exclude the 2,4,3 in the parentheses when getting matches.

I tried something like `(?:^.*?\bC\h+|\G(?!^)|\G(\h+\(\h+\d+\h+\)))` (adding another part to the or clause of the non-matching group, but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user2402616 You can match optional repetitions of the part between parenthesis before matching the digits `(?:^\h*C\h+|\G(?!^))(?:[\h,]*\([^()]*\))*[\h,]*\K\d+` https://regex101.com/r/Jz3NqU/1